# Como pegar Id no retorno de um Post no Web Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

Tenho esse código no `Web Api`:

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(Menu))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Menus.Add(menu);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = menu.Id }, menu);
    }
```

No `Controller` de um projeto `Asp.net MVC` eu recebo a resposta assim:

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/menus", menu);
```

Como pegar o Id no response?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Mude seu código assim:***

```cs
[ResponseType(typeof(Menu))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostMenu(Menu menu)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.Menus.Add(menu);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = menu.Id }, menu.Id);
}
```

*Sendo que no último parâmetro de `CreateAtRoute`, você passa o valor do retorno.*

***Para recuperar:***

```cs
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/menus", menu).Result;    
Int32 Id = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Int32>().Result;
```

*Referência:*

- [ApiController.CreatedAtRoute Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller.createdatroute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Se você só retornasse o inteiro, ficaria assim:

```
var retorno = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<int>().Result;
```

Mas acho que assim ele pode dar problema, porque você criou um objeto anônimo pra retornar. Então use um objeto dinâmico pra serializar o retorno:

```
dynamic retorno = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ExpandoObject>().Result;
var id = content.id;
```